# How can you hide/unhide Reporting Services report parameters via URL query string?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, parameters

I'm trying to figure out how I can dynamically hide/unhide parameters for a Reporting Services report I've created via a URL query string. I've tried reading a whole bunch of stuff I found through a Google search and I've also tried reading various MSDN documents regarding SQL Server, but I have yet to find a way how I can pull this off. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you still want this, but you'd use the [`&rc:Parameters=false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835(SQL.90).aspx) setting in the URL

Edit: that hides/unhides the parameter block as you mentioned.

To set parameters you'd have something like [`&EmployeeID=1234&FieldID=43`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391%28SQL.90%29.aspx) in the URL

So you can set parameters **and** hide them

Edit2: you can only do this at design time. I forget the option, but you can have hidden parameters in the report parameter page that can be set via URL access or via Report manager

Comment: I'm confused as to how this would help me (although I thank you for trying). Would this then allow me to feed something to the report like "FieldID=43" in the query string?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but wouldn't the "&rc:Parameters=false" hide ALL of the parameters? I need to hide a single parameter or two conditionally. I'm going to test right now, but if you could respond to this comment then I'd greatly appreciate it (if it turns out it hides things as I need them, then I'll gladly accept your answer). Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Just got done testing, and it turns out &rc:Parameters=false hides the whole parameter bar. I just need to hide a couple SPECIFIC parameters in that bar; not the whole bar itself.

Comment: It's funny because the documentation he posted clearly states "Show or hide the parameters area of the toolbar"

Answer (score 0):

Well.. this just goes to show my lack of experience with SSRS. My URL was off (apparently you can't preview reports through the Report Manager in the manner I was trying to).

***EDIT:*** Problem still not solved -- I'm now having problems hiding a single report parameter conditionally through a query string (yes I was testing off the wrong URL originally but now I have the right URL and I still have problems when it comes to conditionally hiding a single parameter). If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

(DISCLAIMER: May depend on the version of SSRS you're using, if you're using 2005 & up, you should be good, I believe)

This is possible, in the xml definition for the report, find the definition for the parameter, it should look something like this

```
<ReportParameter Name="YourParameterNameHere">
     <DataType>String</DataType>
     <Prompt>YourParameterNameHere</Prompt>
</ReportParameter>
```

And you can add this line to set hidden to true:

```
 <ReportParameter Name="YourParameterNameHere">
         <DataType>String</DataType>
         <Prompt>YourParameterNameHere</Prompt>
         <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
```

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: I appreciate the response AmalK, and I must admit I found it interesting. However this unfortunately doesn't help me because I need to be able to dynamically set whether it's hidden or not through the URL query string.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. That does not solve the problem, though